# Return type void and Contextual typing

Tags: typescript

The `voidFunc` below returns `void`. However, `v1` returns `true`.

Is this correct?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void

```
type voidFunc = () => void;

const f1: voidFunc = () => {
  return true;
};

const f2: voidFunc = () => true;

const f3: voidFunc = function () {
  return true;
};

const v1 = f1();

const v2 = f2();

const v3 = f3();

console.log(v1);     //true
console.log(typeof v1);  // "boolean"
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is behaving as expected.

It seems that you are confusing the behavior of the static type system, as observed by the TypeScript compiler and a developer writing TypeScript code; with the behavior at runtime, as observed by a JavaScript engine and a developer debugging at a console.

To highlight the difference, here are three *different* TypeScript programs, which happen to behave identically at runtime.

I'll call this one "Too Wide":

```
function foo(x: string | number) {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase()); // compiler error;
    // Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'number'
}
foo("hello!");
```

This one is "Too Narrow":

```
function foo(x: "goodbye!") {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase());
}
foo("hello!"); // compiler error;
// Argument of type '"hello!"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"goodbye!"'
```

And this one is "Just Right":

```
function foo(x: string) {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase());
}
foo("hello!");
```

If you compile these and run them, you will see identical results.  `"HELLO!"` will be logged to the console.  But they are making different claims at compile time, and only "Just Right" is considered to be correct by the compiler.

"Too Wide" says that the function `foo()` will accept any parameter of type `string` or `number`... if so, the implementation of `foo()` is in error, because it tries to access a `toUpperCase()` method on something that might be a `number`.  Someone could change the program so that they call `foo(123)`.  Any code that depends on the value passed to `foo()` being a `string` is doing something wrong.

"Too Narrow" on the other hand, says that `foo()` will only accept the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) string `"goodbye!"`... and if so, the *call* to `foo("hello!")` is in error, because `"hello!"` is not allowed.  Any code that passes something other than `"goodbye!"` to `foo()` is doing something wrong.

Note that the wider a type is, the easier it is to *provide* a value that satisfies it, but the harder it is to *use*... on the other hand, the narrower a type is, the easier it is to *use* a value of that type, but the harder it is to *provide* one.

---

So let's look at functions that return `void`.  A function type like `() => void` is *very wide*.  You have more freedom when *providing* a function like this, but little freedom when *using* it.  That `void` return type means "you should not use the return value of this function for any purpose.  It might return something, but you should ignore it".

For example, the following program is in error:

```
const f: () => void = () => true;
if (f()) { console.log("hi!") }; // error!
//  ~~~ <-- An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness.
```

Even though at runtime you are just checking `if (true) {}`, a perfectly reasonable behavior, you have a bad TypeScript program.  You have said that `f()` returns `void`, meaning that it is wrong to ever use that return value.  Someone can change `f()` so that it returns `new Date()` or `undefined` or anything.  Any code that depends on it being a `boolean` is doing something wrong.

Similarly:

```
const g: () => void = () => new Date();
g().getFullYear(); // error!  Property 'getFullYear' does not exist on type 'void'
```

Again, the provider of a function of type `() => void` is free to return anything they want; in this case it happens to be a `Date` object. But the caller of that function is *not* allowed to treat the return value as if it's a `Date` object.  Doing so happens to be fine at runtime, but it is an incorrect TypeScript program.  I could change `g()` so that it returns anything I want, and then `g().getFullYear()` will probably be an error at runtime as well as at compile time.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAFQPYYOoEsAmqA3sMCuSgGYCuIiALrhiFVgBQAeAXCjPQE64QAcxQAfFCGoQARlH4BKFCQqqUiZjAwAbKADptGYZz30MAVThx5AYTAwobBQoDcKAPTv1GCHFy7+FHl+DH4XMjVyTxQABRDrfnoATxQAcjNLBLsHVJR8DFhJDHogjlw+FGYUZOs0qVl5VIjyAF9m1gw2ACIACyhtQwBCLtdSYDbQSFgEZBQAOVCIMG1ldpo6RirKdm5eASFhJRVI7xAtXQMjEwyrW3tHZ3DVNtVtzt7+oZHw0gnwaHgSFQmAwczA-BCAHdVq9aAwmCw3pweF1hFh8DIklBhkd2qoNGcdPpDMYOKYLLd+NkHqNnmt2B8BhgcW5ohpfP55EEIaEnhRogBBfjCaRQEAlDCUapJWqpRlfXLlIolewwXDCcAyXTVDAoBD8Kb0LmS6Wy1HozHYrpNCbAAkVSg8JwoAC8AD4UAA3DAEV0oZ3u6r8ahQcK4KVsShOI6nc7Eq69XA4lAtVleYKhQbAaIoAB++ZQAB4ALTFlAClhQDhwfiwNVVE01VCpb0EXKIMAgEDFFByaqwI34ViBATUeg9IR1vSke0lYROpSB1tDl3+xcekBQaEAETARqc4WMCj0wig9AAYtQBgBNKDgg8edM8-iDchxDAJZJpU8Xq-aW-grk+SFN2JRVuUEosE2aTLqkQA)